PfSense - Proxmox and subnets
I have a Proxmox server running a pfSense and a Pihole VM (amongs other things) and I am trying to set up a network for my homelab and my day-to-day comptuters.
This is the installation https://imgur.com/a/giy2qZo
Currently Proxmox is behind a wireless router (192.168.1.1). My goal is to remove that wireless router and instead use it as an access point directly connected to the pfSense MAINLAN interface. (there is another router not depicted here, the one from my ISP, so in case something goes wrong I always have a backup Wifi to connect to).
You can also see that it is currently mixing with my original setup before installing pfSense ( the 192.168.1.1/24 network)
Before removing the router at 192.168.1.1. I want to make sure that I am able to reach the PROXMOXLAN network from my computer on the MAINLAN network (10.0.1.1/24) so I can properly reach the PiHole as well as the Proxmox interface.
The probem is that currently my computer, on MAINLAN 10.0.1.2, is not able to reach 10.0.100.8 (PiHole) or 10.0.100.151 (ProxMox GUI) (but is able to reach 192.168.1.26 after being routed by 192.168.1.1)
Currently pfSense is set to allow any traffic between those networks, and I don' t see any logs indicating that any traffic is currently being blocked.
Here are some outputs from various commands:
from my computer:
arp -a
Interface: 10.0.1.2 --- 0x3
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.0.1.1              98-b7-85-20-c8-90     dynamic
  10.0.1.255            ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

tracert 10.0.100.8

Tracing route to 10.0.100.8 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.1 ## The ISP router
  3  142.124.33.232  reports: Destination net unreachable.

I would have expected a hop to see a hop to 10.0.1.1 as it knows about that network and being routed to 10.0.100.8, but instead it goes directly to 192.168.1.1 (which does not know about that network of course). So I guess that is the issue here but I am unsure why this is happening ?
tracert 192.168.1.26

Tracing route to 192.168.1.26 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms     *       <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.26

route print
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1         10.0.1.2     20
         10.0.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.1.2    276
         10.0.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.1.2    276
       10.0.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.1.2    276

From pfSense
Routes
default 192.168.1.1 UGS 11  1500    vtnet0  
10.0.0.0/24 link#1  U   5   1500    igb0    
10.0.0.1    link#6  UHS 6   16384   lo0 
10.0.1.0/24 link#2  U   7   1500    re0 
10.0.1.1    link#6  UHS 8   16384   lo0 
10.0.100.0/24   link#4  U   9   1500    vtnet1

Some notes:

On proxmox, the vmbr1 is attached to a physical interface to allow to get attach an IP address on which to listen to access the GUI.
I created a VM in Proxmox, connected to the PROXMOXLAN, and I am able to connect to proxmox the GUI
All the IP addresses on MAINLAN and PROXMOX lan are provided by the DHCP server on pfSense.


Well, after two days of looking for a solution, I dound it 5min after posting.
TLDR, my outbound NAT rules were set to any destination to go to the WAN gateway instead of the PROXMOX network.
